# replace column values in data.frame with character string depending on column value, in R

Tags: r, replace

I have a data.frame 'data', where one column contains integer values between 1:100, which are coded values for the Isolate they represent.

Here's my example data, 'data':

```
     Size    Isolate    spin
 1   primary   3          up
 2   primary   4        down
 3   sec       6     strange
 4   ter       1       charm
 5   sec       3      bottom
 6   quart     2         top
```

I have another data.frame that contains the key between the integers and the name of the Isolate

```
1  alpha
2  bravo
3  charlie
4  delta
5  echo
6  foxtrot
7  golf
```

This list is 100 Isolates in length, too much to type in by hand with if/else.

I'd like to know an easy solution to replacing the integers in my first data.frame, whic aren't in ascending order as you can see, with the corresponding Isolate names in the second data.frame.

I tried, after researching:

```
 data$Isolate <- as.numeric(factor(data$Isolate,
  levels =c("alpha","bravo","charlie","delta","echo","foxtrot","golf") 
    )
  )
```

but this just replaced the Isolate column with N/A.

Comment: you could use `merge()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hubert said in the comments, this is a simple use-case for `merge`.

Let's say the column names of your second "key" data frame are "Isolate" and "Isolate_Name", then it's as easy as

```
merge(data, key_data, by = "Isolate")
```

The default is for an "inner join" which will only keep records that have matches. If you're worried about losing records that don't have matches you can add the argument `all.x = TRUE`.

If you prefer non-base packages, this is easy in `data.table` or `dplyr` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using `factor`, you could try:

```
data$Isolate <- factor(data$Isolate,
  levels=1:7,
  labels =c("alpha","bravo","charlie","delta","echo","foxtrot","golf"))
```

If you have many levels that are already in their own data.frame, you could automate this.

```
data$Isolate <- factor(data$Isolate,levels=code$No,labels=code$Value)
```

With your second data.frame, `code`:

```
code <- read.table(text="1  alpha
2  bravo
3  charlie
4  delta
5  echo
6  foxtrot
7  golf",stringsAsFactor=FALSE)
names(code) <- c("No","Value")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df$Isolate <- df2[,1][df$Isolate]
#      Size Isolate    spin
# 1 primary charlie      up
# 2 primary   delta    down
# 3     sec foxtrot strange
# 4     ter   alpha   charm
# 5     sec charlie  bottom
# 6   quart   bravo     top
```

You can subset the lookup data frame by the target data frame.

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Size = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("primary", 
"quart", "sec", "ter"), class = "factor"), Isolate = c(3L, 4L, 
6L, 1L, 3L, 2L), spin = structure(c(6L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("bottom", 
"charm", "down", "strange", "top", "up"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Size", 
"Isolate", "spin"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

df2 <- structure(list(V2 = structure(1:7, .Label = c("alpha", "bravo", 
"charlie", "delta", "echo", "foxtrot", "golf"), class = "factor")), .Names = "V2", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```